# The letter 'r', 'o', and 'e' does not work correctly in Android Studio?

Tags: android, navigation, components, nav

When i create a navigation graph, and then navigate to the design tab of my nav graph xml resource file.  I am seeing strange behavior.  When I click on the add fragment icon, and then type the letter 'o' in the "search existing destinations" search bar, my nav graph toggles between portrait and landscape mode.  My letter 'r' key does nothing.  And the letter 'e' toggles open a window beneath my editor.  I am not sure which window this is, but it reads No issues at the top.  I have reinstalled android studio, tried using an external keyboard.  All other letters work normally in the search bar.  Please offer any help.  This is very new laptop, running windows 10 64bit.  I am running Adroid Studio 4.1.1. Thanks.

Comment: Preferences > Keymap > Android Design Tools.
Remove R, E and O shortcuts or replace it with anything else that is not already being used.

Answer (score 2):

As per [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/164163197):

> Yes, thank you for flagging the bug to us, we have streamlined the keyboard shortcuts across design editors in 4.1, and these shortcuts were accidentally shared across layout editor, which caused the focus issues - **the fix will be in 4.2.**
>
> In the meantime, you can go to Preferences > Keymap > Android Design Tools and change the keymap for single-letter shortcuts to something else (i.e. Toggle device orientation O -> Ctrl + O) and that should resolve the search box focus issue. (screenshot attached) Thank you and sorry for the inconvenience!